# Configure Jest to reset mocks between tests with Create React App

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When I add the following code to my `package.json` I get an error saying it is not supported:

```
"jest": {
    "resetMocks": true
},
```

1. I am confused why this is not working as it seems to have been added in this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3802)
2. Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you create your app using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes I did do that.

Comment: my bad, somehow I missed that you mentioned that in the question title itself .  `create-react-app` automatically configures `Jest` with a special setup file, details in the answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

Add the following to `src/setupTests.js`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks()
})
```

**Details**

The [documentation for the `resetMocks` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resetmocks-boolean) states that setting it to `true` is "Equivalent to calling jest.resetAllMocks() between each test."

Looking at the [`Jest` source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/790abe71b9e342170c06a9b75783d929cdd2bb89/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js#L83-L84) shows that the check for `config.resetMocks` happens within a `beforeEach()` and if `true` it calls `jest.resetAllMocks()`.

Apps bootstrapped with `create-react-app` that are using `react-scripts` version `0.4.0` or higher will [automatically run `src/setupTests.js` to initialize the test environment before each test runs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment).

So adding the above code to `src/SetupTests.js` is equivalent to setting the `resetMocks` option to `true` for a non-`create-react-app` app.

Comment: yep, it should be called in `beforeEach()`, good catch @DeveloperDavo